Not able to print pictures with CSS filters using jsPDF and html2canvas
I have a few images, I am arranging them in a grid and trying to print, which works fine. Now, I added a tailwind CSS class 'grayscale' to the div and even the image and tried to print again, but it still prints the colored images in pdf. Here's my code..
const ImagePreviewModal = ({ selectedImages }) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(selectedImages);
  return (
<div id="image-grid">
    {items.map((image, index) => (
      <div className="w-full h-auto ">
        <div className='grid grid-cols-2 gap-3 my-1 px-7 py-4 rounded-md '>
          <img
            src={image.imageSrc}
            alt={`Selected ${index + 1}`}
            className="w-full h-auto rounded-sm border border-white"
          />
          <img
            src={image.imageSrc}
            alt={`Selected ${index + 2}`}
            className="w-full h-auto rounded-sm border border-white"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
)
};

And my print function looks like
const handlePrint = async () => {
    const grid = document.getElementById('image-grid');
    const canvas = await html2canvas(grid);
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    const pdf = new jsPDF({
      orientation: 'portrait',
      unit: 'pt',
      format: 'a4'
    });

    const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    const pdfHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

    const imgWidth = pdfWidth; // Use full page width
    const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width; // Maintain aspect ratio

    // Calculate the new height for the images
    const spaceForText = imgHeight; // Space needed for text equals the height of the image
    const adjustedImgHeight = imgHeight - spaceForText; // Reduce the height of the images

    const x = 0; // Align to left edge
    const y = (pdfHeight - adjustedImgHeight) / 2; // Center vertically

    // Add the image to the PDF
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 20, 20, 555, 555);

    // Add text below the images
    const text = "Your Text Here"; // Change this to your desired text
    const textHeight = 12; // Set an approximate height for the text in points
    const textY = (pdfHeight + adjustedImgHeight) / 2 + 20; // Position 20 points below the images

    const textWidth = pdf.getTextWidth(text); // Get the width of the text
    const centerX = (pdfWidth - textWidth) / 2;
    pdf.setFont("Helvetica", "normal");
    pdf.setFontSize(25); // Set font size
    pdf.text(text, centerX - 10, 650); // Add text (x, y coordinates)

    // Print the PDF
    pdf.autoPrint();
    window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'));
  };

I added various css classes. but it didn't effect. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

What browser are you using?

this might be a stretch but this worked for my own code const canvas = await html2canvas(grid, {scrollY: 0});

please react when thinks work or dont so the issue can be fixed or closed with an valid answer and so that your issue can be resolved faster

It didn't work like that for me. I fixed it by applying the filter before clicking it. @oelimoe

@BlobKat I am using Chrome

@AnshuPatel html2canvas doesn't support css filters afaik
